# Set partition with some conditions

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, set-partition

This is the problem I am trying.

> Define $S_k(n)$ to be the number of partitions of the set $[n]$ so that if $i$ and $j$ are in the same block, then $|i-j| > k$ holds. Show that $S_k(n) = B(n - k)$, for all $n \geq k$.

I first tried to find a bijection and also tried to find a recursive formula for the left hand side, but wasn't succesful. Can anyone help with this question?

Comment: Theorem 8 in [this paper](http://www.austinmohr.com/work/files/stirling.pdf) refines this fact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In what follows, $[a,b]$ will always refer to the integer interval $\{a,a+1,\dots,b-1,b\}$, when $a\le b$.

I shall give a bijective proof of this equality.  Suppose we are given a partition, $P$, of $[n-k]$. We shall output a partition, $P'$, of $[n]$, with the property that any two numbers in the same part are at distance more than $k$.

The $k$ numbers in the interval  $[n-k+1,n]$ will be initially placed in $k$ new parts, each in a distinct part. Call a number $x\in [n-k]$ *bad* if there exists a $y$ in the same $P$-part as $x$ such that $x < y\le x + k$. The idea is that any *bad* numbers in $P$ will be moved to one of the $k$ new parts. We must do this carefully so that these two conditions are satisfied:

1. $P'$ is valid, in the sense that any two numbers in the same part are more than $k$ apart.
2. Our process is reversible, so we can remember where the numbers were moved from, and recover $P$ from $P'$.

For each part in $P$, we first group the numbers into "bad chains" as follows. We say that $x$ is linked to $y$ if they are in the same part and $|x-y|\le k$. The connected components of this linking relation are our bad chains. Each bad chain has a maximal element, which I will call the "leader." Note that the leader itself is not bad, because by definition, a number is bad if there is another number *above* it which is too close, but the leader is greatest in the chain, so has nothing *above* it.

The rules for moving the bad numbers is this:

> For each bad number $x$ in $P$, let $\ell$ be the leader of $x$'s bad chain. If $\ell\equiv x\pmod{k+1}$, then $x$ will remain in its current part. Otherwise, $x$ is moved to the part containing the unique number $z$ in $[n-k+1,n]$ for which  $$n+1-z\equiv \ell-x\pmod {k+1}$$

Finally, I shall prove the required points (1.) and (2.).

1. We have removed all *bad* numbers from the original parts, so we need only prove there are no numbers in the new parts that are too close. The only exceptions are the *bad* numbers $x$ with a leader $\ell$ for which $x\equiv \ell$, but these remaining bad numbers are all in the same equivalence class modulo $k+1$, so the remaining numbers are spaced far enough apart.

   For any $x$ moved to a part containing $z\in [n-k+1,n]$, we have $|x-z|>k$. This is because $\ell \le n-k$, so $$z-x\ge z-(n-k)+\ell-x\equiv 0\pmod {k+1}.$$Since the quantity $z-(n-k)+\ell-x$ is stricly positive, and equivalent to zero mod $k+1$, this quantity must be at least $k+1$, we we have shown $|z-x|\ge k+1$.

   Furthermore, for any $x_1,x_2$ in the same bad chain, we must have $x_1\equiv x_2\pmod {k+1}$, which implies $|x_1-x_2|\ge k+1$.
2. Looking at the outputted partition $P'$, you can determine all numbers that were originally *bad* by looking at the numbers in the parts containing the numbers in the interval $[n-k+1,n]$. This allows you to reconstruct the bad chains, by looking at the connected components of the relation of "at-most-$k$-apart" on these bad numbers. Letting $x$ be the largest number in such a chain, you can then recover the leader of the chain by solving the equation $n+1-z\equiv \ell-x$ for $\ell$, where $\ell$ must be chosen from the interval $[x+1,x+2,\dots,x+k]$. This allows you to return all of the numbers in the new parts to the original parts, so my claimed bijection is indeed reversible.